# Rails query question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got a model called items, with a field called weeks. The content in weeks is as follows:

```
{2011=>["46", "47", "48", "49"]}
```

How can i do something like this:

```
Item.where(:week => week, :year => year)
```

When just passing one week example: 47 and year 2011

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Model
class Item < AR::Base
  def self.with_week(weeek)
    where("week LIKE (?)", "\"#{week}\"")
  end

  def self.with_year(year)
    where("week LIKE (?)", "{#{year}=>")
  end
end
```

usage

```
@items = Item.with_week(47).with_year(2011)
```